# SSIS and SQL Server on Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssis-2012

The SSIS packages I am developing will eventually be deployed to a SQL Server instance hosted on a VM in Azure (IaaS NOT PaaS)

I have read conflicting answers about the type of connection to use in SSIS given SQL in Azure as a component.

I think the answer is

1. Azure PaaS (not VM) you must use ADO.NET
2. SQL Server on VM you can use either ADO.NET or OLEDB.

Can anyone confirm this is the case?

Thanks
Tim

Comment: Hello Timothy, I am looking into this. Will let know once I have an update from the SSIS team. Thanks! Meet

Comment: @meet-bhagdev Thanks for your help!  Looking forward to a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. 
See http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10337.migrating-data-to-sql-azure-using-ssis. This should be good source of document that you should read through. Let me know if you have any more questions. My email is mebha@microsoft.com.

Best,

Meet Bhagdev

Program Manager, Microsoft